# How to get started with JQuery/FullCalendar in my rails app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm relatively new to Rails and Javascript and JQuery are completey foreign to me. I need a little help getting started with JQuery and FullCalendar.

I'm reading this:

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/usage/

But I don't know where to actually put any of the stuff mentioned.

I tried sticking it in the view for my Calendar - but that doesn't do anything and just prints out the contents of my JQuery code.

I'm *guessing* i'm supposed to put this stuff into a *.js file and reference it in my view. But I'd appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You will want to place the Javascript and Jquery code in your assets/javascript folder in either the application.js, or the .js file that matches your controller/model schema.  Then in your application layout file, place the

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='fullcalendar.css' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='fullcalendar.js'></script>
```

lines in the .